# disable postcode validation in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

Does anybody know how to disable the Postcode validation on the checkout page in WooCommerce?

I want to input 'text content' in "billing_postcode" field, but the shop says it's an invalid postcode.

Does anyone know how I can disable Postcode validation or allow text characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 99 );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['validate']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['validate']);

    return $fields;
}
```

You can put this pretty much anywhere, but preferably in a custom plugin or in your theme's `functions.php`

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. I've tried hooking to `woocommerce_default_address_fields` and `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. When I remove `postcode`, WooCommerce validates it regardless. And if I just delete or set `[validate]` to false, it will still validate.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_override_address_fields', 999, 1 );
function custom_override_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

    // set as not required
    $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;

    // remove validation
    unset( $address_fields['postcode']['validate'] );

    return $address_fields;
}
```